# query only returning one result

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

Hey, I am pretty certain I am doing something incorrectly with my lambda expression and that is making it so that I only return a single result. If there is nothing wrong with my query (it has the ability to return multiple results), then I must have an error elsewhere and I should be able to find it. If my results should return more than one result for the third part of the or, only one is being returned. Am I doing something wrong here?

```
var proQuery = from a in solutionContext.Products
                       where a.ID == solutionID ||
                       (a.ParentID == solutionID && a.Versions.All(c => c.VersionNumber == activeNumber)) ||
                       (a.Product2.ParentID == solutionID &&
                            a.Versions.All(c => c.VersionNumber == activeNumber))
                       select a;
```

If there is anymore information you need, I would be happy to help.

Comment: Can you post the code that interrogates proQuery?

Comment: then... what do you do to proQuery?

Comment: Hey guys, sorry if I did not present enough info, but I was pretty certain that everything else with my code was functional and after making the slight adjustment suggested it all works now. Have a good one and thanks for stopping by.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't really enough here for us to go on, but are you sure that the `All`s are correct and shouldn't be `Any`s? Absent additional information, that's one thing to look at.